# Calculate Amount with Java Script by input value in text field

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a php file where I need to calculate total amount by entering a value in a text field.

My form code is like this:

```
<input id='1' name='1' type='text' size='10' value='$visitors' />    
<input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit_button' value='Buy Visitors' />
```

Now what I want is, user will enter some value in text field lets say 15 so it should calculate with price like this

```
15 x 0.60 = 9
```

and answer should show after text field.

Please help Me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
 <input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" onkeyup="calc()" />
 <div id="answer">
 </div>
 <script>
 function calc()
 {
   var vl = document.getElementById('abc').value ;
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = (Number(vl)*0.60);
 }
 </script>
```